# Visual Basic - How to split a String by a string as a delimiter?

Tags: string, visual-studio-2008, split

I want to split a string while the delimiter is a string.

My current code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim xTest As String = "StackThisIsTheSplitterOverflow"
        MessageBox.Show(xTest.Split("ThisIsTheSplitter")(0) & xTest.Split("ThisIsTheSplitter")(1))
End Sub
```

I want the resulting MessageBox to be "StackOverflow".

The resulting MessageBox of the above code is "StackhisIs"

Comment: Try with this: - `xTest.Split("ThisIsTheSplitter", StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: Why don't you respond as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshLine.. Sure. Will add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a 2nd parameter to your `split` function - `StringSplitOptions.None`, to enable split on the words: -

```
xTest.Split("ThisIsTheSplitter", StringSplitOptions.None)
```